# Python regular expression to change date formatting

Tags: python, regex

I have an array of strings representing dates like '2015-6-03' and I want to convert these to the format '2015-06-03'.

Instead of doing the replacement with an ugly loop, I'd like to use a regular expression. Something along the lines of:

```
str.replace('(-){1}(\d){1}(-){1}', '-0{my digit here}-')
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You are looking for `re.sub`. Look up the docs and try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to retrieve the digit from the match. You can replace the hyphen before a single-digit month with `-0`.

Like this:

```
re.sub('-(?=\d-)', '-0', text)
```

Note that `(?=\d-)` is a non-capturing expression because the opening parenthesis is followed by the special sequence `?=`. That's why only the hyphen gets replaced.

Test:

```
import re
text = '2015-09-03  2015-6-03  2015-1-03 2015-10-03'
re.sub('-(?=\d-)', '-0', text)
```

Result:

```
'2015-09-03  2015-06-03  2015-01-03 2015-10-03'
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a regex will accomplish what you want

```
 \d+-(\d)-\d+
```

and so to replace you would use something like

```
import re

target = "2015-6-05"
out = re.sub(r'\d+-(\d)-\d+','(0\\1)', target)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex, you can load it as datetime object and format the string as requested when you print it:

```
import datetime
s = '2015-6-03'        
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')
print "%d-%02d-%02d" % (date_obj.year, date_obj.month, date_obj.day)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2015-06-03
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution alfasin. You are right, this will work for my use case, but I wanted to start learning regex a bit better, so I believe I will end up using the regex implementation. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of...

```
import re

def replaceRegex(what, pattern, filler):
regex = re.compile(pattern)
match = regex.match(what)
if match != None:
    from, to = match.span()
    return what.replace(what[from : to], filler)
else:
    return None
```

Might help you.